# Compare Due Date and send email remind

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation

I'm just working with Share point, so a lot of thing don't know. Please help with my issue.
I'm doing a workflow, 
 - an email will be send to user assigned when new Item created. And a due date to process information.
 - If the information was processed, send email to the user created Item that completed.

### - If the information are not processed until due date, a remind email will be sent again to user assigned with content Today is last day to process ...

I have tried with my WF but It' not correct, just send email when Item created:(
See my WF:[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean if the Due date is today then send Reminder Email?
Can you elaborate it more so that I can understand or clear with your question?

Comment: Yes, I want to send email to remind on the due date. Thank you !!

Comment: Could you pls give example for setup timer job? Like request to do the task in 7 days then count it?

Comment: Hey use below Answer, it's good! instead of timer job!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add flag like new column `Completed(Yes/No type)` to check processed or not.

Try with this:
[image]

Set DueDate is `less than or equal` to Today. Then it will repeat stage when `due date = Today` and you will get email on due date.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you pls explain me about "Pause for 1 days ..."

Comment: Workflow will pause for 1 day. Next day again check due date match with today date, if yes then it will send email.

Comment: You have to do few modification in above logic as per your requirement. I have suggested only solution for your problem.

Comment: Sorry for bother you again !! I have added more photo about my WF setting above. It just send email when I create new Item, if I go to change some thing or out of due date, no email to me. Do I incorrect some thing. Thank you again!!